# Capturing from a html POST form a model in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, input, hidden

The truth i'm new to django and i would like to know how I can capture a value of an input type = hidden in a view of django, using request.POST [ 'address'] so that it can enter a value in my model in this case I want to fill my field direction but does not receive any data appears in the database as empty. This is the code I have so far:

**views.py**

```
def formularioLleno(request):
    form = InformationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InformationForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.ubicacion = request.POST['direccion']
            form.save()
            #return redirect('formas.index')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            form = InformationForm()
    data = {
       'form': form,
    }
    return render_to_response('forma_form.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import forma
class InformationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = forma
        fields = ('nombre', 'telefono')
```

**models.py**

```
class forma(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(verbose_name='nombre', max_length=50, unique=False)
    telefono = models.CharField(verbose_name='telefono', max_length=10, unique=False)
    ubicacion = models.CharField(verbose_name='ubicacion', max_length=15, unique=False)
```

forma_form.html

```
<div id="formularios">
{% block form_content %}
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <div id="ubicacion"></div>
        <input type="hidden" id="direccion" name="direccion" value="hello">
        <button type="submit" onclick="alerta()">Contactar</button>
    </form>

{% endblock form_content %}
```

Comment: Please fix indentation errors in your code.

Comment: Your forms class `InformationForm(...)` specifically states that only two fields should be displayed

Comment: It is not that I want that field to appear in my html code that's why I do not put it, I'm trying to fill that attribute with that hidden input

Answer (score 0):

The reason you aren't seeing the input is that the form field "direccion" is not a member of the class InformationForm.  When you load data from the request with `form = InformationForm(request.POST or None)` the direccion field is not captured.

I would recommend adding a new member to the `InformationForm` form (direccion), and set the widget to `HiddenInput` (read more about Widgets here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/)

This keep the input hidden on the form but will pass the information back to the View. You can then remove the hard coded hidden input HTML from your template.

Comment: Hello Michael the problem with this is that I am modifying with Javascript the value of that input so I want to get that value and put it in the location attribute model

Comment: You can still modify the value of the hidden input via javascript, as the ID will still be accessible (the ID will be the name of the field in the form class).

Comment: You can also directly access the information from the request.POST, rather than relying on the Form constructor to pull that information for you. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict